# objc struct array to swift array

Tags: objective-c, swift

```
-(CGPoint*)func
{
    CGPoint* result = calloc(2, sizeof(CGPoint));
    result[0] = ..;
    result[1] = ..;

    return result;
}
```

how cast this array to swift [CGPoint] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [UnsafeBufferPointer](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_UnsafeBufferPointer_Structure/index.html) to cast it as follows

```
    let pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint> = yourInstance.func()

    let swiftArray = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: pointer, count: 2))

    free(pointer)
```

**EDIT**

If you *really* need to use C arrays, you may want to rewrite the `func` method to something like:

```
- (CGPoint*)pointArray:(NSInteger *)length
{
    int arrSize = 2;
    CGPoint* result = calloc(arrSize, sizeof(CGPoint));
    result[0] = ...
    result[1] = ...

    *length = arrSize;

    return result;
}
```

Then on the Swift side:

```
    var arrayLength: Int = 0
    let pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint> = yourInstance.pointArray(&arrayLength)

    let swiftArray = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: pointer, count: arrayLength))

    free(pointer)
```

Comment: how i can find length of array?

Comment: It's a dynamically allocated array, you can't get the length of the array. Pass the length as a parameter of your func() function.